# Easiest way to make changes to a SQL database wrapped by SugarORM?

Tags: android, android-database

When I was working with vanilla SQL I remember I could pull the database, make changes to it with a 3rd party SQL editor, then push the database back.

Is there an easier way to make some quick changes to my SQL database? Ideally in a viewer like the one that the convenient Facebook library, Stetho, has.

Answer (score 0):

You can still pull the database out and modify it if you like.

If the changes are data, you can do it by executing arbritary SQL using Sugar's `executeQuery` method on app startup like:

```
Item.executeQuery("UPDATE item SET quantity = 100")
```

or via normal ORM methods.

If you want to change the structure of the database via Sugar, making changes to the Model classes should trigger Sugar to automatically make the changes.